# Given a binary search tree and a level, calculate the number of nodes at that level

Tags: java, tree, junit

The problem statement is in the title. If the given tree is empty, -1 is returned. If the tree has *k* levels, and the given level is *m*, and *m > k*, -2 is returned. If neither of these conditions is met, the number of levels is returned.

Here is my implementation in Java and some JUnit tests. The code is also available [on GitHub.](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/NodeCountByLevel)

**Node**

```
package ru.maksim.nodecountbylevel.api;

class Node {

    private final int key;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    Node(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(key);
    }
}
```

**BinarySearchTree**

```
package ru.maksim.nodecountbylevel.api;

public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public BinarySearchTree(int... keys) {
        insertAll(keys);
    }

    Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void insertAll(int... keys) {
        for (int key : keys) {
            insert(key);
        }
    }

    public void insert(int key) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(key);
        } else {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent = null;
            while (current != null) {
                parent = current;
                current = (key < current.getKey()) ? current.getLeft() : current.getRight();
            }
            if (key < parent.getKey()) {
                parent.setLeft(new Node(key));
            } else {
                parent.setRight(new Node(key));
            }
        }
        size++;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
}
```

**TreeAlgorithms**

```
package ru.maksim.nodecountbylevel.api;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

    public class TreeAlgorithms {

        private static final Node END_OF_LEVEL = new Node(0);
        public static final int TREE_EMPTY = -1;
        public static final int NO_SUCH_LEVEL = -2;

        private TreeAlgorithms() {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }

        public static int getNodeCountByLevel(@NotNull BinarySearchTree tree, final int level) {
            if (level < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("level cannot be negative");
            }
            if (tree.isEmpty()) {
                return TREE_EMPTY;
            }

            Queue<Node> nodes = new ArrayDeque<>();
            nodes.add(tree.getRoot());
            nodes.add(END_OF_LEVEL);
            int currentLevel = 0;
            while (currentLevel < level) {
                Node node = nodes.remove();
                if (node == END_OF_LEVEL) {
                    nodes.add(END_OF_LEVEL);
                    currentLevel++;
                    continue;
                }
                Node left = node.getLeft();
                if (left != null) {
                    nodes.add(left);
                }
                Node right = node.getRight();
                if (right != null) {
                    nodes.add(right);
                }
                if (nodes.size() == 1) {
                    return NO_SUCH_LEVEL;
                }
            }
            return nodes.size() - 1;
        }
    }
```

**JUnit tests.**

```
package ru.maksim.nodecountbylevel.api;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;


public class TreeAlgorithmsTest {

    @Test
    void assertEmptyTree() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
        assertEquals(TreeAlgorithms.TREE_EMPTY, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 0));
    }

    @Test
    void assertRootOnly() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(1);
        assertEquals(1, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 0));
    }

    @Test
    void assertFirstLevelIncomplete() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 1));
    }

    @Test
    void assertFirstLevelComplete() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(2, 1, 3);
        assertEquals(2, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 1));
    }

    @Test
    void assertSecondLevelIncomplete() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(10, 4, 16, 2, 7, 12);
        assertEquals(3, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 2));
    }

    @Test
    void assertLevelGreaterThanTreeHas() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(10, 4, 16, 2, 7, 12);
        assertEquals(TreeAlgorithms.NO_SUCH_LEVEL, TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, 20));
    }

    @Test
    void assertNegativeLevelPassed() {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(10, 4, 16, 2, 7, 12);
        assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> TreeAlgorithms.getNodeCountByLevel(tree, -1)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the given tree is empty, -1 is returned. If the tree has k levels, and the given level is m, and m > k, -2 is returned.

Are these specs given our self imposed? If the latter, I suggest changing them.

- The requested level should be >= 1, otherwise throw an illegal argument exception
- In an empty tree, there are 0 levels, so a valid requested level will always be bigger than the number of levels. So I think it makes sense to use the same return value regardless of the tree being empty or not
- How many nodes are at a level higher than the tree? Naturally 0. I think that should be the return value. And notice that there is no other case where 0 will be the return value, so this captures well the case of too high request.

It's interesting what you did with `END_OF_LEVEL` to track the ends of levels.
I think a simpler technique is to use `nodes.size()` to achieve the same.
Something like this:

```
while (currentLevel < level) {
    int count = nodes.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Node node = nodes.poll();
        // add children ...
    }
}
return currentLevel == level ? nodes.size() : 0;
```

Comment: the requested level should be >= 0 (not 1). The root is at level 0

Answer (score 2):

- Using `private static final Node END_OF_LEVEL = new Node(0);` as a sentinel means that the client can't have 0 as a key ever. It is a very strong restriction, and if you mean it you must enforce it, or at least document it.
- An `if (level < 0)` test strongly suggests that `level` should really be an `unsigned int`.
- An unrestricted access to private members (e.g. `left` and `right`) via getters and setters is as <strike>bad</strike> good as making them `public`.

Comment: There is no `unsigned int` in Java